# What's preventing Android from finding a resource file in drawable?

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm working on a bug of my Android application and it only occurs on a Galaxy Nexus with Android version 4.2.2, but works fine on my Nexus 5 with 4.4.2.

Basically it's not able to find a png file on this device.

The png file is only located in res/drawable and here is the structure of my res folder:

```
res/drawable
res/drawable-de
res/drawable-fr
res/drawable-it
res/drawable-hdpi
res/drawable-ldpi
res/drawable-mdpi
res/drawable-xhdpi
res/drawable-xxhdpi
```

What could be preventing Android to fallback to the drawable folder in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing anything about the image its hard to say, but the image may be too large. Alternatively, unless there's a compelling reason not to, you should probably put it in a *dpi folder anyway

Comment: Yes you are right. It turns out the hardware acceleration is on and my image is too large for this phone. Changing to a smaller image worked. Thanks a lot for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

What is the configuration of your device when the drawable resource couldn't be found? When the device language is German, it might happen that one of the resource directory, e.g `res/drawable-de` has taken precedence of the `drawable` directory.

Take a look at [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch) how android find the best matching resources.